# Can't connect to docker deamon with CircleCI integration and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

Trying to set up CircleCI with our project. We use `docker-compose up --build` to run it normally.

This is our config.yml:

```html
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/tmp
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.4.0
    branches:
      only:
        - circleci
    steps:
      - checkout

      - setup_remote_docker

      - run:
          name: Install Docker client
          command: |
            set -x
            VER="v17.12.0-ce"
            sudo curl -L -o /usr/bin/docker-$VER.tgz https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/archive/$VER.tar.gz
            sudo tar x -C /tmp -f /usr/bin/docker-$VER.tgz
            sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker*
            sudo rm /usr/bin/docker-$VER*.tgz

      - run:
          name: Install Docker Compose
          command: |
            VER="1.18.0"
            sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$VER/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
            sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose

      - run:
          name: Start container and verify it's working
          command: |
            set -x
            sudo docker-compose up --build
```

And this error we keep getting as output:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
```

What are we missing?

Comment: Do you really need these `sudo` instructions?
I didn't see `sudo` being used in the circle ci examples.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/

https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-docker/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Comment: No I don't but I saw an answer that needed `sudo` so I placed them on all things just to see if it would work. But I've tried without them as well and there is no change.

Comment: Actually I do need some sudo:s, because I try to place some files where I don't have permission to do that without sudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is your config is doing too much. The advantage to using a CircleCI Docker Convenience image is that tools like Docker are preinstalled. I modified your config to one that should work:

```html
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.4.0
    branches:
      only:
        - circleci
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Start container and verify it's working
          command: docker-compose up --build
```

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, it helped some of our problems but unfortunately we're now experiencing issues with docker not finding package.json. It appears the current working directory is wrong somehow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The default workingDirectory is `~/project`. Regardless of what its name is, your project will be checked out to the workingDirectory by default.

Comment: You can also ask on CircleCI Discuss or open a Support ticket for more specific help.